# Optimization problem, Can you solve it?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

This is the problem that I'm talking about, if you can solve it show me how please!

There is a plane flying at 1km of height and at 700km/h and there is a person 3km away from the plane. At what speed the angle of vision of the person varies?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What makes this an optimization problem?  It is using the chain rule in calculus.  Have you drawn a picture?  What have you tried?  You must be expected to assume the person is on the ground under the track of the plane. How far is the person from the point under the plane?

Answer (score 1):

The distance (hypotenuse of the right triangle) between the person and the plane is 
$$\sqrt{x^2+1^2}$$
by Pythagorean Theorem. The angle between them satisfies
$$\sin \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Implicitly deriving, we get
$$\theta'\cos\theta=2xx'(-1/2)((x^2+1)^{-3/2})$$
Plugging in the initial values $x=3$ and $\theta = 18.4349488^\circ$ and $x'=-700$km/h, we get
$$\theta'=276.7^\circ/hr$$